# Non-Trusted Constraints

Tags: sql-server, data-integrity

I just learned, to my amazement, that foreign key constraints can be non-trusted. This occurs when a constraint is added using `WITH NOCHECK`. When a constraint is non-trusted, it isn't used by the query analyzer for query plan generation.

See:
    https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/03/can-you-trust-your-constraints/

My question is this. When a constraint is non-trusted, is there a property on the constraint I can inspect that tells me this? I guess I could check to see if the constraint was added using WITH NOCHECK, but are there other ways a constraint can get flagged as non-trusted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select *
    from sys.check_constraints
    where is_not_trusted = 1

select * 
    from sys.foreign_keys
    where is_not_trusted = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes [there is a property on the constraint](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1539) accessible through the `OBJECTPROPERTY` function.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('FK_TIMECARD_EMPLOYEEID'), 'CnstIsNotTrusted') = 1
        THEN 'NO' 
        ELSE 'YES' 
        END AS 'IsTrustWorthy?'
```